# I want to output index on max and min element, it for my home work))

Tags: c, for-loop, multidimensional-array, printf, pointer-arithmetic

I want to output index of max and min elemets from each line( in code i want output just Max), there exist coments in the code and photo of my result and result what should be.
Program count max and min elements in correct way:)

````
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 5
int main()
{
    int arr1[N][N] = { 7,  9,  4, 6, 2,
                    3,  5,  4, 7, 2,
                    2,  3,  7, 6, 1,
                    3, 12,  4, 9, 5,
                    6,  2,  8, 1, 3 };
    int i, n;
    int* mn, * mx;
    int temp = 0;
    
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        mx = &arr1[j][0];
        mn = &arr1[j][0];
        for (i = 1; i < N; i++)
        {
            if (arr1[j][i] > *mx)
                mx = &arr1[j][i];

            if (arr1[j][i] < *mn)
                mn = &arr1[j][i];
        }
        printf("Max index is: %d\n", mx - arr1[j][i]);   //here is a problem, but idk how
    }                                                     // to fix this

    return 0;
    /*what it should be look like 
    index of max numver index is: 1
    index of max numver index is: 3
    index of max numver index is: 2
    index of max numver index is: 1
    index of max numver index is: 2

[enter image description here][1]} ```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVbiH.png
````

Answer (score 0):

It seems you mean

```
printf("Max index is: %td\n", mx - arr1[j][0]);
```

instead of

```
rintf("Max index is: %d\n", mx - arr1[j][i]);
```

Pay attention to the length modifier `t` in the format string. It is designed to output difference of two pointers (the type `ptrdiff_t`).

Comment: `&arr1[j][0]` or just `arr1[j]`